# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning after calling async function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I am trying to write a Cloud Function to delete some objects of a user before deleting the user profile on the client. For this, I have a cloud function as well as some async helper functions which run parse queries and delete the items. Unfortunately, I always get the following error when calling the function

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

Below is my code where I tried to make it as simple as possible and still get the error. How can I call async functions within my Cloud Code and still return parse errors as a function response if something went wrong?

Simple summary: I want to write a cloud function which calls async helper functions which are calling methods like `await query.find();`. The user calling the cloud function should either get the result or an instance of `Parse.Error`.

The code which works

```js
Parse.Cloud.define("test_function", async (request) => { 
    throw new Parse.Error(1234, "Test error"); 
});
```

The code which doesn't work

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test_function", async (request) => {
    try {
        testAsync();
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
});

async function testAsync() {
    throw new Parse.Error(1234, "Test error");
}
```

Comment: I don't know the Parse platform, so this is just a note. It might be complaining about your function you pass as a parameter to `Parse.Cloud.define`. Because this function is `async`, it always returns a promise which doesn't have a catch block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but when I only call Parse.Cloud.define("test_function", async (request) => {
    throw new Parse.Error(1234, "Test error");
});, I don't get the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error...

Comment: Did you tried calling the `testAsync();` without the try/catch block. Let the error bubble up on its own. Like: `Parse.Cloud.define("test_function", async (request) => { testAsync(); }); `

Comment: Try awaiting `testAsync()`, then it should work. Right now, `testAsync()` returns a promise, which doesn't throw in our try catch block, but if we await it, it will.

Comment: Thank you @touchmarine, looks like this did the trick! :)